# C++ priority queue with custom compare function in a class

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I am trying to make a priority queue with a custom compare function, as a data member of a class. The code fails to compile if I put the queue inside a class, however it works fine if it is inside the `main` function:

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool cmp(int x, int y) { return (x > y); }

class A {
public:
private:
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp) > pq(cmp); // Error at pq(cmp) : function "cmp" is not a type name
};


int main() {

    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp) > pq(cmp); // no error here
    return 0;
}
```

I am using Microsoft VS2015 for the above code. It makes no difference whether I put the `cmp` function inside the class. Could you explain why this happens and a possible solution for this?

Edit 1:

This line in `main`

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp) > pq(cmp); // no error here
```

does produce an error, but my IDE is not able to detect it. Use `decltype(&cmp)` will eliminate this error.

Comment: Is `decltype(&cmp)` working? (Note the added address of operator)

Comment: @DanielJour It still works only for the `main` function, not the class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First I was thinking about a bug in your compiler, but I [could reproduce](http://ideone.com/C7sIle) it. Then it suddenly became obvious:

```
foo bar(baz);
```

If you look closely, this is the same pattern as in your code. Due to the most vexing parse, this is a **function declaration**!

Thus you're trying to declare a function named `pq` here, returning a priority queue and having a single parameter of type `cmp`. The compiler isn't able to find that type, though.

Changing to use braced initialisation should fix this:

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool cmp(int x, int y) { return (x > y); }

class A {
public:
private:
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(&cmp) > pq{cmp};
};


int main() {
   // priority_queue<int, vector<int>, decltype(cmp) > pq(cmp); // this is wrong, too
    return 0;
}
```

[(Ideone)](http://ideone.com/xjowtr)

<s>Please don't ask me why it's working inside the function, though.</s> It's not working inside the function, either.

Comment: Thanks very much, and the answer is very helpful. The code works fine now.